# MacBook Pro not recognising external monitor

Tags: display

I have a MacBook Pro 14 Inch (2021), which I've connected an old monitor to via an HDMI to VGA adaptor. The monitor isn't recognised, and when I go to display settings the monitor occasionally shows up as recognised and immediately disappears again, the monitor says it's not receiving a signal. Whenever the monitor is connected, the Mac screen occasionally flickers as well.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you have an HDMI to VGA converter - your original post said VGA to HDMI which is not the way your signal runs. VGA to HDMI is far more rare, but is possible to get… & will not work the other way round.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I have got an HDMI to VGA, original post was a mistake.

Comment: My Mac Pro 2019 is not recognising it either, I did the option button thing but nothing, they are absolutely the worst Apple products!